# SQL Query to split result by comma and give result as input of another query

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm trying to use SQL query where the value of one query is used in another query. Here is my SQL query:

```
Select * 
from ( select detection_class, detection_class_id, matched_alert_id, stream_id, track_id, detection_time, frame_id 
       from matched_alert 
       where stream_id = %s 
       group by track_id ) 
where (SELECT ',' || detection_class || ',' FROM alerts WHERE alert_id = %s) LIKE '%,' || detection_class || ',%'
```

this query is stored in `query` variable.
then execute as below:

```
        place_holders = [stream_id, alert_id]
        try:
            with connection.cursor() as cursor:
                cursor.execute(query, place_holders)
                rows = cursor.fetchall()
```

shows error:

```
return sql % params
TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
```

the result of `select detection_class from alerts where alert_id = %s` is like `'car,bus,bike'` but I need result like  `'bus', 'car', 'bike'` to give input of  `where detection_class IN` like `where detection_class IN ('car', 'bus')`.

`alerts table`
[image]
`matched_alert table`
[image]
so, how can I split this result by a comma and make a separate string?

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server - please correct your tags.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/42092313/14853083

Comment: Provide some sample data (as CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO) and desired output for this data (and some `%s` parameter value - provide it too).

Comment: I *removed* the conflicting tags for a reason... As @DaleK said, [[tag:sql-server]] and [[tag:mysql]] are *completely different* products. Only tag the one you *really* using.

Comment: Splitting strings into a table or separate columns is probably THE most common topic. Simple web searching will find many suggestions and discussions.

Comment: @Akina this query works when only one detection class like 'car' because  matched_alert table has only one detection_class store in one row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `IN` you can use the operator `LIKE`:

```
WHERE (
  SELECT ',' || detection_class || ','
  FROM alerts 
  WHERE alert_id = ? 
) LIKE '%,' || detection_class || ',%'
```

and the query as a Python string will be:

```
query = """
Select * 
from ( select detection_class, detection_class_id, matched_alert_id, stream_id, track_id, detection_time, frame_id 
       from matched_alert 
       where stream_id = ? 
       group by track_id ) 
where (SELECT ',' || detection_class || ',' FROM alerts WHERE alert_id = ?) LIKE '%,' || detection_class || ',%'
"""
```

Comment: query = "Select * from (select detection_class, detection_class_id, stat_type,stream_id, track_id, "\
                "detection_time, frame_id from stats where stream_id = %s) where (SELECT ',' || detection_class || ',' FROM alerts WHERE alert_id = %s) LIKE '%,' || detection_class || ',%' "
and execute as below:
place_holders = [stream_id, alert_id]
        try:
            with connection.cursor() as cursor:
                cursor.execute(query, place_holders)
                rows = cursor.fetchall()
I don't understand what is actual problem is, can you please help me to fix this.

Comment: @BikashSaud edit your question and put the code there,

Comment: @BikashSaud also add the tag of the database that you use.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235880/discussion-between-bikashsaud-and-forpas).

Comment: @BikashSaud Replace all `%s` with `?`.

Comment: @BikashSaud are stream_id and alert_id strings?

Comment: stream_id--> varchar, alert_id--> INTEGER.

Comment: @BikashSaud Copy the query from my edited answer as it is.

Comment: Now error like:     return sql % params
ValueError: unsupported format character ',' (0x2c) at index 380

Comment: @BikashSaud did you copy the query as it is? There are no format chars in the string. There are only `?`.

Comment: yes I did. this--> query = """
Select * 
from ( select detection_class, detection_class_id, matched_alert_id, stream_id, track_id, detection_time, frame_id 
       from matched_alert 
       where stream_id = ? 
       group by track_id ) 
where (SELECT ',' || detection_class || ',' FROM alerts WHERE alert_id = ?) LIKE '%,' || detection_class || ',%'
"""

Comment: @BikashSaud this query works fine as it is. I tested it. Just execute cursor.execute(query, ["1", "2"]) for example.

Comment: yeah, this return none when give static parameter but when I tried by giving actual parameter it return error.

Comment: @BikashSaud this means that your parameters are wrong.

Comment: problem is same as first, when I give detection_class = 'car' only it return result. But when detection_class='car,bus' it return none now.

Comment: how do i fiddle sample data.

Comment: Here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27 Post CREATE TABLE statements and INSERT statements for the sample data.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=0315dc7174d7f7aab9f19f226aa125a4

Comment: @BikashSaud for stream_id = '863b1675269e4600ab52a2cf0c418edc' and alert_id = 1 this is the result: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=5b2543acf90f5142e751c2ac165228d7

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235892/discussion-on-answer-by-forpas-sql-query-to-split-result-by-comma-and-give-resul).

Answer (score 1):

You can side-step the problem entirely with an inner join, thus:

```
Select * 
from ( select detection_class, detection_class_id, matched_alert_id, stream_id, track_id, detection_time, frame_id 
       from matched_alert 
       where stream_id = %s 
       group by track_id ) subQ
inner join alerts a on a.detection_class = subQ.detection_class and a.alert_id = subQ.stream_id
```

Incidentally I am not sure what you want a `GROUP BY` for in your sub-query since you are not using any aggregation functions.

Comment: Group by is used because to get data according to track id, this answer works for me.